# how to insert a value and fetch data from disabled text and several checkbox and store in database in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, forms, foreach, controller

I am facing an error.
so the thing is that. I have column name role_permission, where I have to store the roles to each role, here is the UI of form - [image]

As you can see here, I have selected options where users can select roles like -admin, users, editor, and three disabled textboxes which are items whose permission will be set in the database, and the checkbox where users can select the permissions.
Now the main thing is, when the user submit on the button, the data should be saved like this

```
  id    roll_id   item    permission 
  1        1      post     add
  2        1      post     view
  3        1      comment   add
```

As, if the user selects the permission to add, edit, view to post(item), the individual data should be like I showed above, not like an array or something .. each permission should be saved individually pointing to its item.

here is the migration file of this :

```
public function up() {
    Schema::create('role_permission', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('role_id');
        $table->string('Item');
        $table->string('Permission');
        $table->foreign('role_id')->references('id')->on('roles');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Here is the form of it  :

```
<form method="post" action="{{ route('Admin.AssignPermission.save')}}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    @csrf
    @if ($errors->any())
        <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissable">
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
              <ul>
                  @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                  <li>{{ $error }}</li>
                  @endforeach
              </ul>
          </div>
        @endif
        
        <div class="form-group">
            <label> Assign Roles</label>
            <select style="margin-left: 10px;" class="form-select" aria-label="Default Select Role" name="Roles">
                    <option selected disabled>Roles</option>
                    @foreach ($roles as $role)
                        <option value="{{$role->id}}">{{$role->name}}</option>
                    @endforeach 
                </select>
        </div>
        <table class="table table-striped">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th scope="col">#</th>
                <th scope="col">Add</th>
                <th scope="col">View</th>
                <th scope="col">Edit</th>
                <th scope="col">Delete</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>

                <!-- <input name="textbox1" id="textbox1" type="text" />
                <input name="buttonExecute" onclick="execute(document.getElementById('textbox1').value)" type="button" value="Execute" /> -->
                <tr id="post">
                    <th class="col-md-6">
                        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="Items[]"  value="Post" readonly>
                        <input type="hidden" name="selected[]" value="post">
                    </th>
                    <td>
                        <div class="form-check">
                            <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="Add" name="Permissions[]">
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div class="form-check">
                            <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="View" name="Permissions[]">
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div class="form-check">
                            <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="Edit" name="Permissions[]">
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div class="form-check">
                            <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="Delete" name="Permissions[]">
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
              <tr>
                <th class="col-md-6" id="Comments" >
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="Items[]"  value="Comments" readonly>
                </th>
               <td>
                    <div class="form-check">
                        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="Add" name="Permissions[]">
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div class="form-check">
                        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="View" name="Permissions[]">
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                <div class="form-check">
                    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="Edit" name="Permissions[]">
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class="form-check">
                    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="Delete" name="Permissions[]">
                </div>
            </td> 
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <th class="col-md-6" id="Users">
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="Items[]"  value="User" readonly>
                        
                </th>
                <td>
                    <div class="form-check">
                        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="Add" name="Permissions[]">
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div class="form-check">
                        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="View" name="Permissions[]">
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div class="form-check">
                        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="Edit" name="Permissions[]">
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div class="form-check">
                        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="Delete" name="Permissions[]">
                    </div>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>  

          <div style="margin-top:5px; margin-left:1030px;">
              <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit">
          </div>
    </form>
```

and here is the store method of it :

```
public function store(Request $request) {
    
    $data = $request->all();
    $rules = array(
       'Roles' => 'required' ,
       'Items.*' =>'required',
    );

    $validate=Validator::make($data,$rules);
    
    if ($validate->fails()) {
        return redirect()->back()->withInput()->withErrors($validate);
    } else {
       foreach($request->Items as $key=>$Items){
           foreach ($request->Permissions as $key => $Permissions) {
                $form_data = array(
                    'role_id'    => $data['Roles'],
                    'Item'       => $data['Items'],
                    'Permission' => $data['Permissions'],
                );
           }
       }
       $RolePermission = RolePermission::create($form_data);
       $Message = "successfully added";
       return redirect('/Admin/users')->with('success',$Message);
    }   
}
```

, using this method but getting error ??? or how to do this any other method will be helpful
???

Here is the error of that.[image]

here is my structure of the table:
[image]

Comment: you did not show what error message you get.and in the foreach you did not use anything  about`$Items` and `$Permissions`

Comment: @nay you are right ... sorry I am beignner in laravel , so don't know exactly how to do that, copied code from internet .. and tried some my also..  but didn't work.. and I will update my question also

Comment: check I have updated question

Answer (score 0):

You are making things more complicated than it needs to be. First change you view to be similar to this.

```
// name field having [post] for post
<input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="Delete" name="Permissions[post]">
// name field having [comment] for comment
<input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="Delete" name="Permissions[comment]">
```

The above code when submitted through form will result in something like this

```
dd($request->all()); 
// below is output of this
[
   "Permissions" => [
      "post" => ["Add", "Delete"],
      "comment" => ["Delete"]
   ]
]
```

Then in controller you will just sort through those and perform operation as you want

```
  // Looping though permissions
  foreach ($request->Permissions as $itemName => $permissions) {
      // $permissions will be an array ["Add", "Delete"]
      // $itemName will "post"
      // We loop again in permissions to output single data permission
      foreach($permissions as $permission) {
          $form_data = [
             'role_id'    => $data['Roles'],
             'Item'       => $itemName, // post
             'Permission' => $permission, // Add
          ];

          // Perform action here as you suit. Create/Delete based on requirement
          if(!RolePermission::where($form_data)->exists()){
              RolePermission::create($form_data);
          }
      }
 }
```

Comment: hey there.. could you explain the code you wrote

Comment: getting error   ..  Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: @hapuuudddd I have provided the explanations

Comment: as you suggested ... this giving error . all the data doesn't get selcted

Comment: here, I am not able to save the item in permission column

Comment: it's Permission for your case i will update my answer

Comment: hey there thanks , but it is not selecting all the values selected in form , only two are being shown while four are selected

Comment: mean only two ware being showed while doing dd , and I have selected four checkbox